# Remove unused ReentrantLock from ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: java, concurrency, java.util.concurrent, concurrenthashmap, reentrantlock

I have a method in service which fetches entity if exists otherwise it creates new one and returns (for questions purposes let's say entity is a just a string).

Method is executed by multiple threads so if two of them will call method `getOrCreateEntity` with same value and at the same time then they can finish with creating two identical objects, so next `getEntity` call will return two same objects where only one is allowed.

I tried to make lock for each unique entity name by combaining `ConcurrentHashMap` with `ReentrantLock`, in general it works pretty well, problems happens when I trying to remove map entry with lock which is no longer needed, then and some point I'm getting `NullPointerException` when I'm calling `unlock()` method.

I'd like to have correct synchronization for each unique value.

My dummy class to test work concept

```java
public class EntityService {

    private static final ConcurrentHashMap<String, ReentrantLock> lockMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    private static final List<String> entityList = new ArrayList<>();

    public String getOrCreateEntity(String entityName){
        lockMap.putIfAbsent(entityName, new ReentrantLock());
        lockMap.get(entityName).lock();
        try {
            return getEntity(entityName).orElseGet(() -> createEntity(entityName));
        } finally {
            lockMap.get(entityName).unlock(); // <--- Nullpointer 
            if(lockMap.containsKey(entityName) && !lockMap.get(entityName).isLocked()){
                lockMap.remove(entityName);
            }
        }

    }

    private String createEntity(String entityName){
        entityList.add(entityName);
        return entityName;
    }

    private Optional<String> getEntity(String entityName){
        List<String> result = entityList.stream()
                .filter(tabName -> tabName.equals(entityName))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        if(result.size() > 1){
            throw new RuntimeException();
        } else if (result.size() == 1) {
            return Optional.of(result.get(0));
        } else {
            return Optional.empty();
        }
    }
}
```

My test case is pretty simple

```
class ReentrantLockServiceTest extends Specification {

    def service = new EntityService()

    def executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(200)

    def "test lock"(){
        expect:
        for (i in 0..20000) {
            executor.execute{ -> service.getOrCreateEntity(RandomUtils.nextInt(1,4) as String) }
        }
        Thread.sleep(5000)
    }

}
```

What I'm missing? Maybe there are better concurrency classes to perform my desired behavior?